# How do you properly catch the start-byte in parsing serial communication?

Tags: protocols, serial-communication

I am currently designing a protocol for transfer of measurements betweens two embedded systems. The signal path involves a radio link (XBEE Modems). Communication between the microcontrollers and the radio link uses UART.

My dataframes look like this:

[start byte] [timestamp] [message id] [data] [checksum]

On the receiving end, I read the data, wait for the start byte and then parse the rest of the message. However, sometimes the start byte appears in the data part of the frame and my parser starts reading from there.

How do I recognize what the correct start byte is? Can I make my dataframes more robust against this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of the problem you have. Provide source code if necessary to show the issue you have. Provide sample data as well to show the problem you have.

Comment: Also add any information about the `[data]` part. What values are you expecting? What is the "format" of these data?

Answer (score 1):

What about using an escape byte like the Point-to-Point Protocol.
It would ensure that the flag/start byte would only occur at the start (and maybe end) of your message.
Every occurrence of the start (and escape) byte would be replaced by the escape byte, followed by the original byte XOR 0x20.
[image: https://www.embedded-software-engineering.de/effizient-zum-unit-test-unter-c-und-c-gal-841271/?p=1#gallerydetail]

> "On asynchronous links the special byte 0x7d is used as an escape character. Whenever this escape character appears in a PPP frame, the next character in the frame has had its sixth bit complemented, as follows :
>
> The byte 0x7e is transmitted as the 2-byte sequence 0x7d, 0x5e. This is the escape of the flag byte.
>
> The byte 0x7d is transmitted as the 2-byte sequence 0x7d, 0x5d. This is the escape of the escape byte."
> (Stevens,1993,chapter 2.6)

STEVENS, W. Richard. TCP/IP Illustrated, Vol. 1: The Protocols. 1. Auflage. Addison Wesley, 1993. ISBN 0201633469

Answer (score -1):

Do you expect collisions to happen on the medium? Or is this a one way kind of communication?

I think the ethernet protocol relies mainly on an interframe gap. So your receiving decoder could just start happily decoding until there is silence on the medium or the max frame length is reached.

You could also probably include the length of the [data] element in your frame. Then the receiving decoder could stop after the frame length. But I don't think this method is quite as robust tbh. I don't think only relying on "in frame" information is a good idea.